# SQL: pulling in values associated with aggregates

Tags: sql, max, aggregate, teradata, min

suppose I have a table with the following columns:

ID1, ID2, Value

For each ID1, there can be more than one ID2 and corresponding value, ie:

```
a,1,5
a,2,6
a,3,7
```

.

```
Edit: Simpler version of ask:
How can I pull ID1, Max(ID2), Value without having to group on value (i want 
to pull the value that corresponds to the max(id2) and without having to do a second join.
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to provide the following:
ID1, Min(ID2), Max(ID2), along with the values associated with the min/max id2:

a,1,3,5,7

The only way I've come up with is something along the lines of:

```
select 
a.id1, a.min_id2, a.max_id2, b.value as min_value, c.value as max_value
from (select id1, min(id2) as min_id2, max(id2) as max_id2) from table group by 1) a
left outer join (select id1, id2, value from table) b on a.min_id2 = b.id2
left outer join (select id1, id2, value from table) c on a.max_id2 = c.id2
```

This is a hypothetical example, but running this on my data takes an extremely long time. Was hoping there might be some kind of shortcut i'm unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

If you want both min/max on a single line you can use multiple OLAP functions (but all will be calculated in a single step in Explain):

```
SELECT t.*, 
   -- max id2 
   Max(id2) Over (PARTITION BY id1),
   -- and corresponding value
   Last_Value(value)
   Over (PARTITION BY id1
         ORDER BY id2
         ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND Unbounded Following)
FROM table AS t  
QUALIFY -- row with min id2
   Row_Number()
   Over (PARTITION BY id1
         ORDER BY id2) = 1
```